# Unlisting nested lists and plotting using ggplot

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, data.table

I have a monstrous nested list structure of my own making that looks like this:

```
str(CMaster)
List of 4
 $ :List of 6
  ..$ :List of 5
  .. ..$ :List of 15
  .. .. ..$ : num [1, 1:14] 0.144 0.2 0.256 0.352 0.446 ...
  .. .. ..$ : num [1, 1:47] 0.144 0.2 0.375 0.54 0.694 ...
etc
$ :List of 6
      ..$ :List of 1
      .. ..$ :List of 15
      .. .. ..$ : num [1, 1:14] 0.144 0.2 0.256 0.352 0.446 ...
      .. .. ..$ : num [1, 1:47] 0.144 0.2 0.375 0.54 0.694 ...
```

The structure is fixed but the last list of 15 could go up to 150K and I need to try to plot this structure. I'd like to try and plot boxplots categorised by the List of 4 variable for each of the List of 6 similar which condenses all of the numerical data for the List of 15 into this example. Do I need to unlist it all first? Is there an easier way to make a data.frame or data.table which preserves the names of the lists and makes them factors for plotting?

```
dfs <- lapply(CMaster, data.frame, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

**EDIT: I've added example code**

Example code (that gets close to the real structure).

```
D<-list()
DNSIM<-list()
DTime<-list()
DMaster<-list()

  
for(CC in 1:4){
  for(t in 1:6){
    for(N in 1:5){
    for(i in 1:15){
      
      Dmatrix=runif(15)
      D[[i]]=Dmatrix
    }
    DTime[[t]]=D
    }
    DNSIM[[N]]=DTime
  }
  DMaster[[CC]]=DTime
 }
```

[image]

**Dput**

It's too big to copy and I my organisation won't allow a sharable link to onedrive. Any easy workaround?

**EDIT2**

```
tibble(lists = CMaster) %>% 
+   mutate(CleaningType = row_number()) %>% 
+   unnest_longer(lists, indices_to = "TimePoint") %>% 
+   unnest_longer(lists, indices_to = "Replicate") %>%
+   unnest_longer(lists, indices_to = "BehaviourObservation")
# A tibble: 1,800 x 5
   lists                 BehaviourObservation Replicate TimePoint CleaningType
   <list>                               <int>     <int>     <int>        <int>
 1 <dbl[,14] [1 × 14]>                      1         1         1            1
 2 <dbl[,47] [1 × 47]>                      2         1         1            1
 3 <dbl[,11] [1 × 11]>                      3         1         1            1
 4 <dbl[,40] [1 × 40]>                      4         1         1            1
 5 <dbl[,40] [1 × 40]>                      5         1         1            1
 6 <dbl[,34] [1 × 34]>                      6         1         1            1
 7 <dbl[,92] [1 × 92]>                      7         1         1            1
 8 <dbl[,31] [1 × 31]>                      8         1         1            1
 9 <dbl[,5] [1 × 5]>                        9         1         1            1
10 <dbl[,103] [1 × 103]>                   10         1         1            1
# … with 1,790 more rows
```

So I tried to add another sub-sub-list and now get an error of incompatible sizes. Any thoughts about this please?

```
tibble(lists = CMaster) %>% 
+   mutate(CleaningType = row_number()) %>% 
+   unnest_longer(lists, indices_to = "TimePoint") %>% 
+   unnest_longer(lists, indices_to = "Replicate") %>%
+   unnest_longer(lists, indices_to = "BehaviourObservation") %>%
+   unnest_longer(lists, indices_to = "sub_sub_observation") 

Error: Can't combine `..1$lists` <double[,14]> and `..2$lists` <double[,47]>.
✖ Incompatible sizes 14 and 47 along axis 2.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Comment: Could you share a piece of your data (using `dput()`) that I could fiddle around with? As far as I know, the easiest way is to unnest it. Probably using something like `purrr::map_dfr(.x, .f, ..., .id = "id_col")`.

Comment: Thanks for replying so quickly. I've included a similar data structure example because the output from dput is too big to copy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't mind using the tidyverse, find below some code to rectangle your data using `tidyr::unnest_longer`. See [here](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/hoist.html) for a nice tutorial on how to use `unnest_longer` (and in general how to turn nested lists into data.frames).

I'm not sure what's the difference between `observation` and `sub_observation` in the result, and if this plot is what you actually want.

This might be (too) slow on your large data-set.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(lists = DMaster) %>% 
  mutate(facet = row_number()) %>% 
  unnest_longer(lists, indices_to = "boxplot") %>% 
  unnest_longer(lists, indices_to = "observation") %>%
  unnest_longer(lists, indices_to = "sub_observation")
  
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(boxplot, lists, group = boxplot)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_wrap(~ facet)
```

Which gives a data.frame with `facet` (1 to 4), `boxplot` (1 to 6), `observation` (1 to 15), `sub_observation` (1 to 15) and `lists` (your actual numeric values), and the following plot:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and the link. I'm finding that I end up with a double[,random length] in the final nested list. But when I add another %>%
  unnest_longer(lists, indices_to = "sub_sub_observation"); I get this error: Error: Can't combine `..1$lists` <double[,14]> and `..2$lists` <double[,47]>.
✖ Incompatible sizes 14 and 47 along axis 2.

Comment: It seems like the column consists of matrices. I think if you convert them to vectors, it should work: `%>% mutate(lists = map(lists, as.vector)) %>% unnest_longer(lists, indices_to = "sub_sub_observation")`

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of completeness, the `melt()` function from the `reshape2` package has a method for lists which recursively melts each component.

```
library(magrittr) # piping used to improve readability
reshape2::melt(DMaster) %>% 
  head()
```

> ```
>        value L3 L2 L1
> 1 0.20653283  1  1  1
> 2 0.96955498  1  1  1
> 3 0.07924116  1  1  1
> 4 0.98602539  1  1  1
> 5 0.72998492  1  1  1
> 6 0.16022710  1  1  1
> ```

Combined with `ggplot()`

```
library(ggplot2)
reshape2::melt(DMaster) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = L2, y = value, group = L2)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_wrap(~ L1)
```

we get
[image]

---

`reshape2::melt()` has also a method for arrays. So, the issue with matrices as list elements [reported by the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62949713/unlisting-nested-lists-and-plotting-using-ggplot#comment111322638_62950197) is covered as well.

Here is a dummy example of a double nested list of matrices

```
rep(list(list(matrix(1:4, ncol = 2), matrix(11:19, ncol = 3))), 2) %T>% str() %>% 
  reshape2::melt()
```

> ```
> List of 2
>  $ :List of 2
>   ..$ : int [1:2, 1:2] 1 2 3 4
>   ..$ : int [1:3, 1:3] 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
>  $ :List of 2
>   ..$ : int [1:2, 1:2] 1 2 3 4
>   ..$ : int [1:3, 1:3] 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
> ```

> ```
>    Var1 Var2 value L2 L1
> 1     1    1     1  1  1
> 2     2    1     2  1  1
> 3     1    2     3  1  1
> 4     2    2     4  1  1
> 5     1    1    11  2  1
> 6     2    1    12  2  1
> 7     3    1    13  2  1
> 8     1    2    14  2  1
> 9     2    2    15  2  1
> 10    3    2    16  2  1
> 11    1    3    17  2  1
> 12    2    3    18  2  1
> 13    3    3    19  2  1
> 14    1    1     1  1  2
> 15    2    1     2  1  2
> 16    1    2     3  1  2
> 17    2    2     4  1  2
> 18    1    1    11  2  2
> 19    2    1    12  2  2
> 20    3    1    13  2  2
> 21    1    2    14  2  2
> 22    2    2    15  2  2
> 23    3    2    16  2  2
> 24    1    3    17  2  2
> 25    2    3    18  2  2
> 26    3    3    19  2  2
> ```